# Do I need to write a jQuery plugin to get a hover event while using a draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working on a set of connected tabs with lists on each tab. The desired functionality is to be able to drag a list item from a list on tab A to a list on tab B. The user would pick up the li from an ul on tab A, hover for about 1 second on tab B, the tab switches automatically and then the user can drag down to the ul on tab B and drop the li into that list.

It appears that jQuery ui is now intercepting all mouse events once a draggable starts and not letting them through. I see another post on here [jQuery - stopping a hover event while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338063/jquery-stopping-a-hover-event-while-dragging) which describes the opposite problem, but it was made in 2010 and now hover *won't* work while dragging a draggable.

I dug into jQuery ui V. 1.8.17 and found that jQuery UI is intercepting all mouse actions, checking if any plugins want to interact with them, and if not passing them along to the browser. In draggable's case, it appears that it is intercepting there, and just executing it's own actions, which makes sense. As far as draggable is concerned, once something is picked up, *all* mouse input *is* for it. But in my case, draggable is not doing anything with the hover input.

I know my event fires while A) Not carrying a draggable, just hovering over the tab. B) Holding the mouse button down, before, during and after hovering, without carrying a draggable, but NOT when carryign the draggable along.

I've tried binding the to the hover, mouseenter, mouseover, sort, sortover events with no luck.

So, what are my options? DO I need to patch jQueryUI, or write a custom draggable plugin (borrowing heavily from the current), or is there an easier way that I'm missing?

I can provide code if needed, but it is pretty straightforward. Let me know if you need additional details and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I solved this with a 2 line patch to droppable. 
Add a property to the droppable code:

`hoverable: false,`

I did this on line 26.

Then, on line 91 (version stated above) add a check against that property to the conditional that checks for accept:

`if (this.accept.call(this.element[0],(draggable.currentItem || draggable.element)) || this.hoverable == true) {`

Then, I made what I wanted to fire the hover event a droppable without an accept that is inconsequential, but setting hoverable: true.  This allows you to make other DOM elements interact with Draggables, but not be accepting droppables.

Not sure if anyone else needed this problem solved, but hope this helps.

Comment: You should [accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).